# modify file using awk or sed

Tags: sed, awk, vim, ldap

I have a text file contains ldap data in the give below format, our default structure says every user must have its own respective "home directory" but in given below i found many users have the same home directory and that is "homeDirectory: /home/UGstudent/2013" so i want to change it to "homeDirectory: /home/UGstudent/2013/xyz" means i need to take the same name as in "uid: abc" field of each user and append it to "homeDirectory: " field.

```
dn: uid=abc,ou=People,dc=abc,dc=com  
uid: abc   
cn: abc def
objectClass: account  
objectClass: posixAccount  
objectClass: top  
objectClass: shadowAccount  
shadowLastChange: 15923  
shadowMax: 99999  
shadowWarning: 7  
loginShell: /bin/bash  
uidNumber: 10000  
gidNumber: 9000  
homeDirectory: /home/myworker/2013/abc  
gecos:: QWpheSBLasdfkshdfksdkfhUJTTVMxMywJU1RVLA==  
structuralObjectClass: account  
entryUUID: 74dec3aa-0fb6-4d86sfs-962e-432ea83c75e0  
creatorsName: cn=Manager,dc=abc,dc=com  
createTimestamp: 20160806091411Z  
userPassword:: e1NIQXKSJFkHkjhfskDAvS2NwYWxXcm4zY2JEL2wxYVk9  
entryCSN: 20160121043505.309136Z#000000#000#000000  
modifiersName: uid=abc,ou=People,dc=abc,dc=com  
modifyTimestamp: 20160121043505Z  

dn: uid=xyz,ou=People,dc=abc,dc=com  
uid: xyz  
cn: xyz jakas  
objectClass: account  
objectClass: posixAccount  
objectClass: top  
objectClass: shadowAccount  
shadowLastChange: 15923  
shadowMax: 99999  
shadowWarning: 7  
loginShell: /bin/bash  
uidNumber: 1260  
gidNumber: 9000  
homeDirectory: /home/myworker/2013  
gecos:: QWtzaGFqIFByZfdsfdsfdsgDAzLAlCU01TMTMsCVNUVSw=  
structuralObjectClass: account  
entryUUID: 81fc5c44-6d63-4d4a-bb74-7ae5f12bbeef  
creatorsName: cn=Manager,dc=abc,dc=com  
createTimestamp: 20160806091411Z  
userPassword:: e1NIQXkjfshgjdsJMQTB2SsdfSGFMekpZSkV1ZkZsWlE9  
entryCSN: 20150118182228.898901Z#000000#000#000000  
modifiersName: uid=xyz,ou=People,dc=abc,dc=com  
modifyTimestamp: 20160118182228Z
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: i tried it using awk last time but as far i only got able to extract the users having same home directory by using command "awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS=ORS="\n\n"}$14!="abcd 123"' textfile.txt". well it will be great help for me if some one write a code for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic `awk` alternative:

```
awk '
    /^uid:/ {
        uid=$2
    }
    /^homeDirectory:/ {
        if ($NF !~ uid"$") { $NF = $NF"/"uid }
    }
    { print }
    ' text.file
```

Comment: @Sahni I'm glad I could help.

Comment: hello @FloHimself, I again need a bit help from the same problem, i.e. if the structure have the below lines exactly in same way : 

`objectClass: account`

then structure should be modified to :

`objectClass: person`
`sn: $uid`

$uid means to the field uid contains

Answer (score 0):

awk file :

```
$1=="uid" { uid=substr($2,2) ; }
$1=="homeDirectory" { printf "%s: /home/myworker/2013/%s\n",$1,uid ; next ;}
{ print ;}
```

which

- basically remember uid
- print a fixed home dir, base on fixed year and last uid.

to be called with

```
awk -F: -f tmp.awk < yourinputfile
```

where

- `-F:` use : as separator
- `-f tmp.awk` use the awk file

Comment: thanks for the code, but the above code is changing every user's home directory instead of it i want to change homeDirectories only who have same i.e. /home/myworker/2013/ with their respective uid names. thanks again in advance

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` version will keep entries intact that already have a user ID as part of the homeDirectory:

```
awk -F ": *" '
    $1=="uid" { uid = $2 }
    $1=="homeDirectory" && $2=="/home/myworker/2013" { $0=$0"/"uid }
    { print }
' infile > outfile
```

(Note: your data should not have trailing spaces. To clean up that as well you can add a command `{ gsub(/ +$/, "", $2 }` as first command of the `awk` program.)